# Why is the maximum propotion of MII 2/3 in the ordered tetrad analysis? How is it different from normal recombination?

Tags: genetics, recombination

My textbook says that the maximum propotion of MII gametes in the ordered tetrad analysis is 2/3, and if we put it into the formula *RF(recombination frequency)=MII/2(MI+MII)*, we can find out that the maximum RF is 1/3, instead of 1/2. The textbook persumes that each of the 4 gametes(actually 8) are randomly dominant or recessive, and gives a perfect provement, but I wonder if the persumption really exists.
I've found out that four-strand double crossing over provides 4 recombined gametes, while it's MI in this model, which may make the calculated RF smaller than real RF, but I can't figure out why it is 1/3 from the aspect of exchange and recombination.

`My textbook:Genetics:Analysis of Genes and Genomes`
Maybe my English isn't very good:(